# Change sharepoint site language?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I've create a site in french language , now i wanna change the default language to English ,there is no possiblity from site settings , how can i do it ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert the base site from French to English, but you can enable the English language pack.

Go to Site Settings and click on language Settings and click English and click OK. You will need to do this for every site in your collection you want to have available in other languages.

Comment: thanks but i wanna put english as a default language

Comment: You can't. You would have to recreate the site in English, and then enable French as an additional language like I described.

Answer (score -1):

This article should help you: 
http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2008/04/29/changing-the-language-of-an-existing-sharepoint-site.aspx

Comment: Direct database modifications are not supported and not an option for SPO.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise it was Sharepoint online. Sorry.

Comment: yeah it's online

Comment: is there any other solution?

Comment: a frayed knot: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2883180